# Vite can't resolve export {default as component}

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, vite, rollup

I have such a problem. I installed a plugin that adds a react component to vs code and does default things like import react, etc.

so this plugin generates a folder with a component and an index.js in which the public export writes like this:

```
export {default as  CreateArticlePage} from './CreateArticlePage';
```

at first I thought it was some kind of strange syntax, but after Googling I realized that this thing is in the interop and should be handled normally in

but in the console and during the build, he writes errors in the style

[error example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouHlk.png)

at the same time, not all components that were declared that way

I am writing on the react template in vite

Please help me solve and understand what the problem is.

Configs:

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  ssr: false,
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "social-network",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.4",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.24.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.24.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.66",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.22",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.6",
    "husky": "^9.0.11",
    "lint-staged": "^15.2.2",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "vite": "^5.1.0"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": [
      "eslint --fix",
      "vitest"
    ]
  }
}
```

there are no other confics like babel

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you in App.jsx you need to import a named export, because no default export exists:

```
import { CreateArticlePage } from './pages/CreateArticlePage'
```

This index.js file:

```
export {default as  CreateArticlePage} from './CreateArticlePage';
```

Does not export a default. It re-exports the default export from `CreateArticlePage` as a named export - `CreateArticlePage`

Answer (score 0):

You've exported the default as a named constant.
You just need to import as such

```html
import {CreateArticlePage} from '../pages/CreateArticlePage'
```